# Angle of rotation around Z-axis (Inclined phone)

Tags: java, android, rotation, accelerometer, angle

I need to get an accurate value of my android device's angle of rotation around Z-axis while the device is inclined (not lying flat).
I reached this angle using accelerometer sensor and calculated the angle using this code:
    float[] values = event.values;

```
double x = values[0];
double y = values[1];
double z = values[2];

double mag = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);

// Normalize the accelerometer vector
x = x / mag;
y = y / mag;
z = z / mag;

int inclination = (int) Math.round(Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(z)));
if (inclination < 25 || inclination > 155) {
    return Orientation.Error;
} else {
    double rotation = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x, y));
```

but when the devices rotates in a high speed this value becomes unreliable.
How can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance,